# Angularjs get scope attribute without using isolated scope in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I did a little experiment based on my project

I create 2 directive, one using isolated scope and the other one is not..

the question are :

1. is there a way to get scope attribute without using isolated scope ?
   because in my project I didn't have an isolated scope for the custom
   directive environment and also I need to access the parent scope
2. could I manipulate the dom using angular.element('#' + scope.id) ?
   if not is there a way to do this ?

this is the unisolated custom directive

```
<test-directive item="item" content="item.context"></test-directive>
```

this is the js codes

```
app.directive('testDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: false,
    template:"<div>test directive</div>",
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      console.log(attr.item); //I want it like the result gives in line 39
      console.log(attr.id); //I want it like the result gives in line 41
      console.log(attr.content); //I want it like the result gives in line 43
      console.log(scope.name);
    }
  }
});
```

this is the isolated one

```
<isolated-directive id=item.id item="item" content="item.context"></isolated-directive>
```

this is the js codes

```
app.directive('isolatedDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope:{
      item:'=item',
      id:'=id',
      content:'=content',
    },
    template:"<div>isolated directive</div>",
    link:function(scope,elm,attr) {
      console.log(scope.item.id);
      console.log(scope.id);
      console.log(scope.content);
      console.log(scope.name); //I want it like the result gives in line 27
    }
  }
});
```

and this is the working [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WHcwFGa4H4phnZQzjCAw?p=preview)

anyone care to help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scope: true` and the scope will prototypically inherit from the location it is inserted. However, if all you need is access to the parent scope, you can always use `$parent`, even in an isolated scope. It is not recommended, but it is possible.

Comment: wow apparently without using scope:true I could use it also, thanks for your reply.. btw what if I want to manipulate the element? like using this angular.element('#' + scope.item.id); is that possible ? @unobf

Answer (score 0):

Q1:

```
app.directive('testDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: false,
        template:"<div>test directive</div>",
        link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
            console.log(scope[attr.item]); //I want it like the result gives in line 39
            console.log(scope[attr.id]); //I want it like the result gives in line 41
            console.log(scope[attr.content]); //I want it like the result gives in line 43
            console.log(scope.name);
        }
    }
});
```

Q2:

basically the parm `elm` in link function is your directive related DOM. if you really want the `scope.item.id` in your DOM attribute, use `ng-attr` to define your attributes like below. note that `angular.element` is just used to wrap a DOM to JQuery element but not used for DOM finding.

```
<isolated-directive ng-attr-id="{{item.id}}" item="item" content="item.context"></isolated-directive>
```